# what is the difference between `hasArg` and `exist` to test if an argument exists as an input in a R function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, arguments

I am wondering what is the difference between `hasArg()` and `exist()` in a R function. It seems that `hasArg()` works while `exist` does not work to test if an argument exists in the input of a R function.

```
f_exists <- function(x){
  if(exists("x")){
  print("exist")
}else{
  print("Non existence")
}}
```

When I test this `f_exists` function, the `exist` seems not to be working in the ifelse statement:

```
> f_exists(x = 1)
[1] "exist"
> f_exists(x)
[1] "exist"
> f_exists()
[1] "exist"
```

However, if I use the function `hasArg()` in the ifelse statement, the function works:

```
f_hasArg <- function(x){
  if(hasArg("x")){
    print("exist")
  }else{
    print("Non existence")
  }
}

> f_hasArg(x = 1)
[1] "exist"
> f_hasArg(x)
[1] "exist"
> f_hasArg()
[1] "Non existence"
```

However, it is weird that `exist()` and `hasArg()` seem to be working in a reversed way when I test them in the environment:

```
> rm(list = ls())

> exists("x")
[1] FALSE
> hasArg("x")
[1] FALSE

> x <- 1
> exists("x")
[1] TRUE
> hasArg("x")
[1] FALSE
```

I am asking why is `hasArg()` and `exists()` work in a different way in R functions and in the environment? Is there a underlying reason for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f_exists()` returns "exist", because variable `x` actually exists inside function `f_exists`, yet it is bound to a special "missing" value. Using that value would result in an error ("argument 'x' is missing, with no default), but as the value is not used, no error is reported.

`hasArg("x")` returns false, because it is looking really at (formal) arguments of the surrounding function call, not at any variables in the current environment. The documentation has more details: `?exists` and `?hasArg`.

To check whether a value has been explicitly provided by the caller for a formal argument `x` of a function, one can use `missing(x)`. If the same could be achieved by providing a default argument expression, it is probably cleaner to do so.